# Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 1. Actual: 123295

Tags: google-sheets

I'm getting the following error with this code. Not sure why is happening since the ranges are actually the same size.

I'm filtering information from another spreadsheet that has over 70k rows and goes from A:AF, which the information updates dynamically with another a script. With that in mind, the formula in this post filters data from that spreadsheet.

UPDATE: After removing the comma and placing ; I got this information. I deleted some rows in the different spreadsheet, but makes no sense since all the ranges are the entire column and not any specific row number.

*Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 1. Actual: 123295.*

1st try
[image]
2nd try
[image]

```js
=sort(FILTER({
IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15,"Audit!A:E"),IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15,"Audit!I:I"),IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15,"Audit!AC:AC"),IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15,"Audit!AE:AE")},

IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15,"Audit!B:B")<>"Time between your actions",

IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15,"Audit!B:B")>=Links!G3,
REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15,"Audit!H:H"),"Start")=FALSE,
REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15,"Audit!H:H"),"End")=FALSE,
REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15,"Audit!I:I"),"End")=FALSE
),1,false)
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Can you please add some background, i.e. what you want it to do, how it works, etc.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with that formula. You should not be using that many IMPORTRANGE calls in a formula. But re: what you asked about, you're trying to process an array, but you haven't wrapped the formula in `=ArrayFormula(     )`. That alone may get you the results you were expecting.

Comment: Same error. I'm sad
I attached the image in this post

Comment: Post updated with background info

Comment: links!G3 is number right?

Comment: Yes, is in duration format and like this 00:10:00.000

Answer (score 1):

first, run this fx and allow access:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15, "Audit!A1")
```

then, try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15, "Audit!A:AE"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col9,Col29,Col31 
  where Col2 >= "&Links!G3&"
    and not lower(Col8) matches '.*start.*|.*end.*'
    and not lower(Col9) contains 'end'
  order by Col1 desc")
```

### update 1:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15, "Audit!A:E"),
        IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15, "Audit!H:I"),
        IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15, "Audit!AC:AC"),
        IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15, "Audit!AE:AE")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col7,Col8,Col9 
  where Col2 >= "&Links!G3&"
    and not lower(Col6) matches '.*start.*|.*end.*'
    and not lower(Col7) contains 'end'
  order by Col1 desc")
```

### update 2:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15, "Audit!A1:AE5000"); 
        IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15, "Audit!A5001:AE10000"); 
        IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15, "Audit!A10001:AE15000"); 
        IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15, "Audit!A15001:AE20000"); 
        IMPORTRANGE(Links!E15, "Audit!A20001:AE25000")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col9,Col29,Col31 
  where Col2 >= "&Links!G3&"
    and not lower(Col8) matches '.*start.*|.*end.*'
    and not lower(Col9) contains 'end'
  order by Col1 desc")
```

Comment: Access was allowed data seems to be loading, I'm waiting, no error so far

Comment: I got: Result too large

Comment: @mau try the updated variant

Comment: I updated this post with the error code. Not sure why we get this error if we are not defining row lenght but rather columns.

Comment: @mau can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: I cannot, I have too much sensitive data to show and is very complicated to replicate an example

Comment: @mau try update 2 and if it works continue the importrange pattern

Comment: Is not working because all the data is being pulled in one row